# In Netlify CMS's config.yml, how to specify that the site is in a subdirectory of the repo?

Tags: github-pages, netlify-cms

I have a repo at github.com/some_user/some_repo, and it's set to deploy via GitHub pages on the ./docs subfolder of the master branch, to example.com.

./docs/admin/config.yml (and example.com/admin/config.yml) has the following code:

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: some_user/some_repo
  branch: master
  base_url: https://my-authentication-server.example.com
```

How do I tell netlify CMS that the code is in the ./docs subfolder and not the root of the codebase? Is there something like this?

```
backend:
  ...
  site_directory: docs
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no such directive, however, each individual file or folder should be set to reside in the subdirectory, for example:

```
...
folder: docs/_posts/
...
file: docs/_data/my_custom_data.yml
...
```

etc. Then it works.